# My app crash after downloading it from appstore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I just did an update of my application to app-store and after approval i downloaded it and it crashed. I have not seen any problem during testing at all.

One thing that could be a problem is that i lowered the approved IOS release from 4.2 to 4.0, maybe that is the problem but it does not explain why i did not have any problem on my device.

Anyone that can help me with some ideas so i can find the problem as i do not even know where to start looking except the IOS level?

Here is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: B95E9513-DBCD-40F1-A24C-7116285D66F8
CrashReporter Key:   f7781ad5687b1a1cbfdcc3c014ba4524bdb0e48e
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport [2300]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/68D41895-E120-4C76-9952-    3F7CB6E1EBB2/FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport.app/FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport
Identifier:      FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-10-20 07:36:58.974 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33df7a1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e313b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e29bf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32eeaa64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x333aa06c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32ee8e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32ee8e8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32ee8f5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x333a8c84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3614f48a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] +   62
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3614f4c4 +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
11  Foundation                      0x34514e28 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:] + 68
12  Foundation                      0x345279c4 +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:] + 28
13  FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport          0x0000e808 0x1000 + 55304
14  FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport          0x0000d6c4 0x1000 + 50884
15  CoreFoundation                  0x360bf56a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
16  UIKit                           0x34f51ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78
17  UIKit                           0x34f51e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
18  UIKit                           0x34f51e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 32
19  UIKit                           0x34f51b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 350
20  UIKit                           0x34f5241c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 336
21  UIKit                           0x34f50bee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 362
22  UIKit                           0x34f50568 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 256
23  UIKit                           0x34f3930c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 292
24  UIKit                           0x34f38c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
25  GraphicsServices                0x35873e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
26  CoreFoundation                  0x36126a90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
27  CoreFoundation                  0x36128838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
28  CoreFoundation                  0x36129606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
29  CoreFoundation                  0x360b9ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
30  CoreFoundation                  0x360b9dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
31  GraphicsServices                0x35873418 GSEventRunModal + 108
32  GraphicsServices                0x358734c4 GSEventRun + 56
33  UIKit                           0x34f63d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
34  UIKit                           0x34f61800 UIApplicationMain + 664
35  FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport          0x00002b4e 0x1000 + 6990
36  FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport          0x00002b18 0x1000 + 6936

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33df8fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x32fc9032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x32fca03a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x32fc95ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e3258a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e32bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33df5c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33df5758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x361272b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36129562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x360b9ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x360b9dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x3588227e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e3130a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e32bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33df83ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e326d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e32bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
r4: 0x3f66848c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x058ec89c      r7: 0x2fdfdfc0
r8: 0x3fd58bf8    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x362212f0     r11: 0x3fd4b964
ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfdfb4      lr: 0x34e263bb      pc: 0x34deca1c
  cpsr: 0x080f0010

Binary Images:
0x1000 -    0x1dfff +FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport armv7  <81da61ecfb1337cf82536279719bbccd>  /var/mobile/Applications/68D41895-E120-4C76-9952-3F7CB6E1EBB2/FamiljeQuiz-    Frågesport.app/FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <4d3190188cbf32a8a73f32a8b5bb7adf> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3117f000 - 0x3119cfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x311da000 - 0x314c7fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x314f1000 - 0x31529fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3156f000 - 0x3161efff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3173b000 - 0x3183ffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x318b8000 - 0x319d9fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31a16000 - 0x31a58fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31b2b000 - 0x31b30fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <f019bc513a6a37f4a79555b3ffb2a777> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31b39000 - 0x31b62fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31c7e000 - 0x31c83fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e32cf2d48a1f3060b372ca7623e4a12b> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31d0e000 - 0x31d11fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33844000 - 0x33849fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3384f000 - 0x33850fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <7dd4acfe150831e0ae82296587e67e7f> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x33929000 - 0x33a16fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33a17000 - 0x33a76fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33af1000 - 0x33b37fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33b71000 - 0x33b71fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x33b87000 - 0x33b8dfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33e9b000 - 0x33ee5fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <e98c3fd72ba43d02aac24b08f7219eb7> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33ef6000 - 0x33fa7fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33fb1000 - 0x33fb3fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x33fb8000 - 0x33fc5fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x34399000 - 0x3445dfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <a89ef30f6d663254babb6329ce02ca3d> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34482000 - 0x34485fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <53908d448e9e32418652a4afee5bc578> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x344bb000 - 0x344bffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3453b000 - 0x34554fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x345b3000 - 0x345b3fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3477a000 - 0x347affff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x347b0000 - 0x347e7fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x347fb000 - 0x34810fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34811000 - 0x34812fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x34a87000 - 0x34a90fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x34b1a000 - 0x34c34fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34c43000 - 0x34c4afff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34c81000 - 0x34cb9fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <416c77100b453e3f838831c4c857f8c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34ddb000 - 0x34df2fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <c4ebe7eb2e6c3a2d9bd3620a4d6dbc0e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x34df3000 - 0x34e74fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <17ee3fe220c23b1f898d21ba25b2bcac> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x34ec6000 - 0x34f05fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <64cf947dd8423eeeb677f81dd3eb2d9d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x34f06000 - 0x34faffff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x34fb0000 - 0x34fbbfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x34fbc000 - 0x34fc0fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <362fdd2de66f3e189b5d139c9669a9e3> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x35324000 - 0x35324fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x354ee000 - 0x3560dfff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35681000 - 0x35682fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <3e0b7d6754cd33669c0680525f03ede1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3568f000 - 0x356e0fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x356e1000 - 0x35700fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35701000 - 0x3573efff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3573f000 - 0x3573ffff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3574a000 - 0x3577dfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x35807000 - 0x3589cfff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x358c8000 - 0x358d6fff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x35c17000 - 0x35c1efff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x35d36000 - 0x35d3bfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x35d3c000 - 0x35dabfff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35dac000 - 0x35db8fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x35e10000 - 0x35e1dfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x35f2a000 - 0x362b7fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x36615000 - 0x36615fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36617000 - 0x36646fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36647000 - 0x36649fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x366be000 - 0x366c3fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x366f9000 - 0x367b8fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36838000 - 0x3683afff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x36843000 - 0x36863fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x36864000 - 0x36870fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x36871000 - 0x36e7cfff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36ee4000 - 0x36ee8fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x36ee9000 - 0x3703dfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x370a6000 - 0x3718bfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x371ab000 - 0x371acfff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x371ae000 - 0x371eafff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37305000 - 0x3735afff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x374ac000 - 0x374aefff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x374cf000 - 0x375d7fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x37797000 - 0x37798fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <0fa08e1bb47a3d179072a933d1726597> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
```

Here is an extract from the console, with more information:

```
Oct 20 07:36:58 unknown UIKitApplication:com.thefroghouse.PRODUCTNAMErfc1034identifier[0x8e0f][2300] <Notice>:  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Oct 20 07:36:59 unknown ReportCrash[2304] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport[2300]



Oct 20 07:36:42 unknown FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport[2300] <Warning>: xx: 3672
Oct 20 07:36:42 unknown FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport[2300] <Warning>: eOF 99999
Oct 20 07:36:42 unknown FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport[2300] <Warning>: #entities in DB after   insert: 2331
Oct 20 07:36:58 unknown FamiljeQuiz-Frågesport[2300] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to     uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL    initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'
```

Comment: Did you add any new features that call files such as level three beat on hard mode?

Comment: No, i changed background picture, added a quick start button and lowered the required IOS from 4.2 to 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Bundle resources missing**

   Sometimes, if you don't explicitly select Product->Clean and then build, it can leave some of the build intermediates around from previous builds, which are not present in newer builds (including `.xib` files and image resources).

   If you changed your background image, but accidentally forgot to put it in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build step, it could be working during testing due to it being present in your build directory locally, but when you built for distribution it didn't copy the new background image in. So when you start up the app, it may crash immediately due to referencing a non-existent background image.

   Although, that doesn't explain how it got approved in the first place.. try purging build files like I said, and also uninstalling the app from your testing device(s) entirely before you test again.
2. **High memory usage**

   The changes you made might have pushed the memory allocation at one particular point (during the loading of a question) just beyond the mark that your testing device can handle before emitting a memory warning level 2 (which would likely get the app terminated by Watchdog). This would make sense if you tested it with less apps open, but now you're trying to run it with a bunch of other apps running in the background.

   Follow @brian's advice and get crash logs, but also read the Console log for the device to see if Watchdog killed the app. You might want to try closing all other apps on your testing device in case it's just a problem of having too many apps running on your specific device.

---

*EDIT:* Look at lines 10 and 11 from your stack trace:

```
10  CoreFoundation  0x3614f4c4 +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
11  Foundation      0x34514e28 -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:] + 68
```

It's not able to construct a file URL (a link to a file on the local system). So, you may have tried to initialise an incorrectly-formatted URL. If the path doesn't actually exist, the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath%3a) states:

> If path does not exist in the file system, the method assumes that it represents a file and does not append a trailing slash.

So it must be that you've either passed `nil` by accident to the method, or the format of the URL is invalid.

Comment: This is a quiz app and what happen is that it starts up ok but when starting questions it crash either the first question or later

Comment: well i do not use the 'initFileURLWithPath' method so i guess i pass nil somewhere, the question is to find where.

Comment: why does it not crash in the simulator?

Comment: I have identified when it crash, when someone answer wrongly, but i cannot simulate the problem on the device in testing mode???

Comment: Hmm. According to the stack trace, the program goes from your code on line 13 to the `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` method on line 12. So I'd be surprised if you *didn't* have a call to `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Plug your device into your Mac, open up XCode organizer and import the crash reports. You should be able to symbolicate them and use the stack trace to determine the cause of the crash.

If there are no crash reports then maybe your app is crashing before it even starts up. Which could indicate a problem with the Info.plist or a code signing problem. Though I don't think that is the case if it was approved.

Comment: In Xcode, go to Window->Organizer, select the Devices tab, select your device (it should have a green indicator next to it). There's a Device Logs section. The reports are imported to there automatically. Obviously you need to plug it in first.